# nginx on localhost - wildcard domains and wildcard subdomains

Tags: nginx, wildcard-subdomain, nginx-config

I configured nginx (and dnsmasq) to listen to `example.test` and `*.example.test` wildcard subdomain. Everything seems to work fine. Here is nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~(\.)?example\.test$;
...
}
```

Now I want to respond to all other `*.test` domains from their own directory on disk. I just don't know how to make it happen, following config doesn't work (just disables above configuration):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name \.test;
...
}
```

Even following configuration has same effect:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~(?!(\.)?example)\.test;
...
}
```

Both these configs work, but disables *.example.test and example.test configuration and responds to them just as other `*.test` domains.

---

Here is my question:

How can I configure nginx to respond to `*.test` but respond to `example.test` and `*.example.test` in a different way?

Answer (score 4):

After a wasting a whole day, I finally managed to fix the issue.

For those who may find themselves in such a confusing situation, here is the solution:

```
# First server block for default configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.test$; # matches domain names (e.g. anything.test)
...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~(\.)?example\.test$ example.test; # matches all subdomains (e.g. subdomain.example.test and sub.subdomain.example.test) as well as example.test
...
}
```